# Get multiple rows from a subquery SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Basically I have 2 Tables, the first with the raw material amount (QT) for each serial number and the second one with how much raw material was spent (Qt_Added) on batch's production. Like this:

Table 1

```
+----------+------------+-----+
| Code_Raw | Serial_Raw | Qt  |
+----------+------------+-----+
|        1 |          1 | 100 |
|        1 |          2 | 150 |
|        2 |          1 |  80 |
|        1 |          3 | 100 |
+----------+------------+-----+
```

And Table 2

```
+------------+----------+------------+----------+--+
| Code_Batch | Code_Raw | Serial_Raw | Qt_Added |  |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+--+
|          1 |        1 |          1 |       80 |  |
|          2 |        1 |          1 |       10 |  |
|          3 |        1 |          2 |      150 |  |
|          4 |        1 |          3 |       80 |  |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+--+
```

I tried to do a query for a specific `Code_Raw`, show me how much left for each serial number, But worked only when there's a single `serial_raw`.

My query:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         Serial_Raw,
         (Select QT From Table_1 where Code_Raw = 1) - Sum(qt_added) as Total_Remaining 
     from
         Table_2
     where 
         Cod_Raw = 1
     group by 
         Serial_Raw) e
where 
    Total_Remaining > 0
```

but it throws this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

And I expect :

```
Serial_Raw     Total_Remaining
-------------------------------
    1                10
    3                20
```

Is there a struct problem or another way to do this?

I'm using SQL Server 2014

Thanks guys

Comment: I don't follow your math.  Can you explain what is happening here better?

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you got your expected result from these 2 tables ?

Comment: Sure, I  added all spend Raw material for a specific "batch" of Raw. Then i took the diference from the initial amount in the "batch" as total remaining. Hope that is clear now

Comment: What is `spend raw material` ? what is the `initial amount in the batch` ? These thinks may be clear to you, but not to us. We dont know your database and your business

Comment: How did you get `10` for serial raw `1` ?

Comment: Well,  I didnt get my expected results yet. I want to get this Result. My querry returns a error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: First explain your logic, what is the formula to get the expected results ?

Comment: Okay, the Raw material with Code_Raw 1, has 3 serial_Raw. The Serial_Raw 1 ,with Qt 100,was  spent in Code_batch 1 and 2, respectively, 80 and 10 ( any units like pound, gallons). So a took the diference between QT(initial amount) for Serial_Raw 1 and the total of spent (90). So, the Remaing Material for Serial_Raw was 10. Sorry for the confuse text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE
(   CodeRaw INT,
    Serial_Raw     INT,
    Qty INT)


DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE
(   
    CodeBatch INT,
    CodeRaw INT,
    Serial_Raw     INT,
    QtyAdded    INT)

    INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1,1,100)
    INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1,2,150)
    INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(2,1,80)
    INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES(1,3,100)

    INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(1,1,1,80)
    INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(2,1,1,10)
    INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(3,1,2,150)
    INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(4,1,3,80)

    --Inner table has the summary of the Quantity added with columns CodeRaw and SerialRaw. Outer table make join with inner table and just substruct with the Qty and Sum of Qty Added.  
    SELECT t2.Serial_Raw, t1.Qty - t2.QtyAdded AS Total_Remaining  FROM @tbl1 t1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT CodeRaw, Serial_Raw , SUM(QtyAdded) QtyAdded FROM @tbl2
                    GROUP BY CodeRaw, Serial_Raw) AS t2 ON t2.CodeRaw = t1.CodeRaw AND t1.Serial_Raw = t2.Serial_Raw
    WHERE t1.Qty - t2.QtyAdded > 0
```

Comment: I think it's a better answer without the `WHERE` clause, but maybe that's just me. A little explanation of why that works for the OP's benefit would make it a better answer, but +1 anyway for including the table set up scripts since the OP didn't provide them.

Comment: @EricBrandt I have added a comment to understand the query, Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: oh, i needed to use JOIN. Thanks for your hepl guys

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, this might be what you are after

```
declare @tbl1 table (CodeRaw INT, Serial_Raw INT, Qty INT)
declare @tbl2 table (CodeBatch INT, CodeRaw INT, Serial_Raw INT, QtyAdded INT)

insert into @tbl1 values (1,1,100), (1,2,150), (2,1,80), (1,3,100)
insert into @tbl2 values (1,1,1,80), (2,1,1,10), (3,1,2,150), (4,1,3,80)

select t2.Serial_Raw,
       t3.Qty - sum(t2.QtyAdded) as Total_Remaining
from   @tbl2 t2
  inner join ( select t1.Serial_Raw,
                      t1.CodeRaw,
                      sum(t1.Qty) as Qty
               from   @tbl1 t1
               group by t1.Serial_Raw, t1.CodeRaw
             ) t3
             on t2.Serial_Raw = t3.Serial_Raw
            and t2.CodeRaw = t3.CodeRaw 
group by t2.Serial_Raw, t3.Qty
```

So in `t2` we get all distinct `Serial_Raw` values, and sum their `QtyAdded` from the first table.
In t3 we get all `Qty` values from the 2nd table.
All we need to do is join them together and subtract

The result of this query is

```
Serial_Raw  Total_Remaining 
----------  --------------- 
1           10  
2            0  
3           20
```

Comment: You understood right. Again, Thanks for the help and patience